# Uniqe 1 column and his properties

Tags: mysql, sql

Now i got this results:

| Person | Property | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Age | 52 |
| Jack | Car | GAZ |
| John | Age | 42 |
| John | Car | Audi |
| Martin | Age | 38 |
| Martin | Car | BMW |

But i need set limit for 2 values in column "Person", like this:

| Person | Property | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Age | 52 |
| Jack | Car | GAZ |
| John | Age | 42 |
| John | Car | Audi |

When i use LIMIT in SQL query i got this:

| Person | Property | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Age | 52 |
| Jack | Car | GAZ |

Comment: Please show us your query.

Comment: @diiN__________ i put query to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by <order col>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

The `<order col>` specifies which two you want.  Remember:  SQL tables are *unordered*.  So, if you want arbitrary values, use `NULL` or `person`.  Or if you have another ordering column, use that.

EDIT:

I think RosieC might be correct in interpreting the question.  If so, for that, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by person) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

This returns the first two people alphabetically, which seems consistent with the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this gives the required result. Wouldn't this give the first two records for each person. If I have understood the question correctly the OP wants all the records for the first two people (so Jack and John but not Martin).